# curl POST request is not working

Tags: rest, curl, post

I am trying to consume POST URL using curl. Curl request is as below:

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type    : application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "Authorization : OAuth oauth_consumer_key=2IaG9fzswU1f8bJ2bWCIIQ" -X POST -d "{'consumer_id':'google_bps','app_id':'google_bps_app','user_id':'bala.gto3','first_name':'bala','last_name':'gto3','email':'bala.gto3@gmail.com'}" https://ec2-54-189-116-121.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/cec_baseline/api/users/save
```

Although JSON data is accurate I am getting bad request error.

Response is as below:

```
{"status":400,"code":0,"message":"Bad Parameters: Consumer Id and Application Id Mandatory!","description":"BAD REQUEST","result":[]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have set `Content-Type` as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so you have to send form URL encoded data :

```
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" \
        -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" \
        -H "Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=2IaG9fzswU1f8bJ2bWCIIQ" \
        -X POST \
        -d 'consumer_id=google_bps&app_id=google_bps_app&user_id=bala.gto3&first_name=bala&last_name=gto3&email=bala.gto3@gmail.com' \
        https://ec2-54-189-116-121.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/cec_baseline/api/users/save
```

which gives :

```
{"status":200,"code":1,"message":"Successfully Saved!","description":"","result":[]}
```

Moreover, it seems your endpoint doesn't support JSON, when issuing your previous request with `Content-Type: application/json` it gives :

```
{"status":400,"code":0,"message":"Content Type must be application\/x-www-form-urlencoded!","description":"BAD REQUEST","result":[]}
```